# Efficient way to use selfdestruct() as safe ether transfer option?

Tags: solidity

I have been getting into mitigating reentrancy issues and safe ether transfer recently and have come up with the following 'safe transfer' code. 
Workflow:

1. deploy contract Foo
2. send ether to Foo
3. execute function safeTransfer specifying the destination address and value in wei

   ```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

   contract Interface {
       function pay();
   }

   contract Foo {

       function safeTransfer (address _to, uint256 _amount)
       {
           Bar a = new Bar(_to);
           a.transfer(_amount);
           Interface b = Interface(a);
           b.pay();
       }

       function () payable {}
   }

   contract Bar {

       address payee;

       function Bar (address _payee)
           {
               payee = _payee;
           }

       function () payable {}

       function pay () 
           {
               selfdestruct(payee);
           }
   }
   ```

At ~150k gas this is rather expensive but it works. I am aware of the [pull payment best practise](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/payment/PullPayment.sol) but would much prefer a convenient automated payments method. Any thoughts on how to potentially optimise this idea for use as payment option in a contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to mitigate reentrancy vulnerability, [transfer()](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#common-patterns) has a gas stipend of only `2300` which is enough only to publish an event. In other words, as long as you stick to `transfer it's not possible to call back your contract.

There is a small potential for improvement if you pass _payee directly to pay() function saving a bit of storage:

```
function pay (address _payee) 
    {
        selfdestruct(_payee);
    }
```

But I'm afraid that if you want to use a selfdestruct safety feature you will need to pay for contract creation every time - which is a very expensive operation.

Comment: Yes - true - but I also want to refund bids on items once a higher bid comes in and using transfer to a contract without a payable fallback can hold my contract hostage without a safe transfer method or pull withdrawal.

Comment: Now I see your point. Very interesting approach. There is a small potential for improvement if you pass _payee directly to pay() function saving a bit of storage. But I'm afraid that if you want to use a `selfdestruct` safety feature you will need to pay for contract creation every time - which is a very expensive operation.

Comment: Oh yes - thanks! Good point re passing _payee directly to pay(). I am going to go down the safe withdrawal route though. My method is just too expensive.

Comment: If this answer helped or solved your issue, please mark it as accepted or upvote ;)

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include passing _payee directly to pay()?

Comment: I've moved the content from our comments to the answer.